# Emoji problem reading json file in python

Tags: python, emoji

I have a json file with a string containing emojis

```
{
   "messages": "This is a test -bla-bla test."
}
```

My python code is:

```
with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
print(config["messages"])
```

The output is:

> This is a test ðŸ“‘-bla-bla test.

How can I solve this emoji encoding problem?

Comment: Try this print(json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False))

Comment: Nothing change, I get the same output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to make sure you save / read the file with the right encoding.

```
with open('config.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as config_file: 
    config = json.load(config_file)
print(config["messages"])
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unidecode library. First make a quick pip install installation within the terminal:

```
pip install unidecode
```

Then you can use following code:

```
import unicodedata
from unidecode import unidecode


def deEmojify(inputString):
    returnString = ""

    for character in inputString:
        try:
            character.encode("ascii")
            returnString += character
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            replaced = unidecode(str(character))
            if replaced != '':
                returnString += replaced
            else:
                try:
                     returnString += "[" + unicodedata.name(character) + "]"
                except ValueError:
                     returnString += "[x]"

    return returnString



string = 'hello__emoji','___free___world'

print(deEmojify(string))
```

**Output**

```
hello__emoji___free___world
```

I hope I could help you out a bit. :)